# Display results from Bolts of a storm cluster on browser

Tags: runtime, apache-storm

Is it possible to display the results that are derived from the processes in the bolts of a storm process on a web browser or a UI during runtime? How is it done?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are looking for but it is very much possible to write any bolt output to file. You simply need a working bolt which whites down whatever passed to it in a file. Your logic to write stream to  a file should be inside the bolt's `execute(Tuple tuple)` method.
Is that what you are seeking?

**UPDATE**

How about putting a queue (Kafka/Krestel) in between your bolt and Websockets. I've found this article [here](http://blog.avisi.nl/2013/07/01/tools-for-building-a-real-time-analytics-platform/)  which says

> In order to easily integrate between Storm and the front-end (through
>   WebSockets) I chose Apache Camel to do the heavy lifting for me. By
>   having the bolts in the Storm topology write their output to an
>   ActiveMQ queue, I could create a Camel route that subscribes to this
>   queue and push the messages to WebSockets, like so:

```
    public class StreamingRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
              from("activemq:storm.queue")
                .to("websocket://storm?sendToAll=true");
       }
   }
```

Also found [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/integrating_websockets_and_jms_with) article talking about integration between `JMS and Websockets`

Comment: I am actually trying to run a storm process that scans a file and emit the results of the processes of the bolts, during runtime, on to a web browser. Any idea? I am using web sockets to achieve obtaining the data on the browser, without any request being sent. I guess the part about the file was misleading. Will remove it. Thanks for your answer though.